# How to set up azure application gateway to allow intranet access only and block the internet traffic?

Tags: azure, gateway, azure-application-gateway, azure-webapps

I have a setup like this

1. There is a website hosted in a VM in IIS.
2. There is an Azure Application gateway in-front which redirects the traffic to the website hosted in VM.
3. There are the NSGs, VNet and subnets for the Application gateway.

**The requirement is to restrict the access to the site from internet while allowing intranet access only?**

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Could you please take some time to answer it

Comment: @1690193 Could you please take some time to answer it –

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Application gateway you are using, if V1, attach the application gateway to private VNET-->Subnet and only attach private ip to gateway. If it is V2 just remove the public IP listener.

Answer (score 0):

Application gateway is a reverse proxy. If you add VM's private IP as backend pool of your Application gateway, then application gateway will use its instance IP to forward the http request to your VM.

So you can add a NSG to your VM's subnet to only allow Application gateway subnet IP range and deny internet traffic on port 80,443.

It is applicable for both V1 and V2 SKU.